# Linq Exclude columns in children

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I am trying the following: Given a list of dynamic objects perform a GROUP BY using a list of columns provided. Here's what I have so far:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    dynamic[] data = {
        new { A = "A1", B = "B1", C = "C1", D = "D1", E = "E1", F = "F1"},
        new { A = "A1", B = "B1", C = "C1", D = "D1", E = "E1", F = "F1", G = "G1"},
        new { A = "A1", B = "B1", C = "C1", D = "D1", E = "E1", H = "H1", I = "I1"}
    };

    var newList = data.GroupBy(row => new { row.A, row.B, row.C, row.D, row.E })
        .Select(
            y =>
                new
                {
                    A = y.Key.A, B = y.Key.B, C = y.Key.C, D = y.Key.D, E = y.Key.E,
                    Children = y.ToList()
                });

    var str = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(newList);

    Console.Read();
}
```

This works as per my needs. However, I want to get rid of some additional columns that appear as part of the `Children` field. Here's the output I am getting now for `str`:

```
[
   {
      "A":"A1",
      "B":"B1",
      "C":"C1",
      "D":"D1",
      "E":"E1",
      "Children":[
         {
            "A":"A1",
            "B":"B1",
            "C":"C1",
            "D":"D1",
            "E":"E1",
            "F":"F1"
         },
         {
            "A":"A1",
            "B":"B1",
            "C":"C1",
            "D":"D1",
            "E":"E1",
            "F":"F1",
            "G":"G1"
         },
         {
            "A":"A1",
            "B":"B1",
            "C":"C1",
            "D":"D1",
            "E":"E1",
            "H":"H1",
            "I":"I1"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

What I would ideally want is the following:

```
[
   {
      "A":"A1",
      "B":"B1",
      "C":"C1",
      "D":"D1",
      "E":"E1",
      "Children":[
         {
            "E":"E1",
            "F":"F1"
         },
         {
            "F":"F1",
            "G":"G1"
         },
         {
            "H":"H1",
            "I":"I1"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Any suggestions on how this can be achieved? What I do know is that there can be certain number of fields that are common across objects (e.g., A,B,C,D,E) but have no control over the others (e.g., F, G, H etc.)

Comment: What is the rationale behind these `Children`? Why doesn't the 3rd child follow the same pattern as the 2nd child?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`ExpandoObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject(v=vs.110).aspx) class to store only the properties which are unique for each item and reflection to select those unique properties.

Here's why I managed to scratch up in LinqPad:

```
dynamic[] data =
{
    new { A = "A1", B = "B1", C = "C1", D = "D1", E = "E1", F = "F1" },
    new { A = "A1", B = "B1", C = "C1", D = "D1", E = "E1", F = "F1", G = "G1" },
    new { A = "A1", B = "B1", C = "C1", D = "D1", E = "E1", H = "H1", I = "I1" }
};

var keyProperties = new[] { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E" };
var newList = data.GroupBy(row => new { row.A, row.B, row.C, row.D, row.E }).Select(
    y => new
         {
             A = y.Key.A,
             B = y.Key.B,
             C = y.Key.C,
             D = y.Key.D,
             E = y.Key.E,
             Children = y.Select(
                 item =>
                 {
                     IEnumerable<dynamic> itemProps = item.GetType().GetProperties();
                     List<dynamic> properties =
                         itemProps.Where(p => !Enumerable.Contains(keyProperties, p.Name)).ToList();
                     var result = new ExpandoObject();
                     foreach (var property in properties)
                     {
                         var value = property.GetValue(item, null);
                         if (value != null)
                         {
                             ((IDictionary<string, object>)result).Add(property.Name, value);
                         }
                     }
                     return result;
                 }).ToList()
         });
var str = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(newList);
```

And the result is:

```
[
  {
    "A": "A1",
    "B": "B1",
    "C": "C1",
    "D": "D1",
    "E": "E1",
    "Children": [
      {
        "F": "F1"
      },
      {
        "F": "F1",
        "G": "G1"
      },
      {
        "H": "H1",
        "I": "I1"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

**Edit**

To merge elements at the child level you need to change the projection a bit.

First of all, the `Select` becomes a `SelectMany` to return a collection of `KeyValuePair<string, object>` which subsequently will be grouped by name and concatenated into an array:

```
Children = y.SelectMany(item =>
{
    IEnumerable<dynamic> itemProps = item.GetType().GetProperties();
    List<dynamic> properties = itemProps.Where(p => !Enumerable.Contains(keyProperties,p.Name)).ToList();
    var result = new ExpandoObject();
    foreach(var property in properties)
    {
        var value = property.GetValue(item, null);
        if(value != null)
            ((IDictionary<string, object>)result).Add(property.Name, value);
    }
    return (IDictionary<string, object>)result;
}).GroupBy(prop => prop.Key, prop => prop.Value)
.Select(g => 
{
    var result = new ExpandoObject();
    ((IDictionary<string, object>)result).Add(g.Key, g.ToArray());
    return result;
})
.ToList()
```

It's not the most elegant code but it should do the work.

Comment: +1 Thanks a ton! One last question: Would it be possible to merge even the elements at the child level? For instance, instead of getting two elements with F, I need F: Array. Therefore, if I had F1 and F2 instead, I'd just have F: ["F1", "F2"]. Any suggestions on how I can achieve that? Thanks!

Comment: @Legend, please see the edit on how to merge the child items.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much for your help.